# C++ - adding to same vector gives different results

Tags: c++

So I have this:

```
std::vector<GameObjectsDatabaseContainer*> GetDatabase();
std::vector<GameObjectsDatabaseContainer*> _container;

std::vector<GameObjectsDatabaseContainer*> GameObjectsDatabase::GetDatabase()  {
    return _container;
}
```

If I do this:

```
auto * godc = new GameObjectsDatabaseContainer();
_container.push_back(godc);
```

It works, however If I do this it does not:

```
auto * godc = new GameObjectsDatabaseContainer();
GetDatabase().push_back(godc);
```

Why is that? My understanding is that `GetDatabase()` is returning basically `_container` and when I try to add data to it via `GetDatabase()` it is not working. Why ?

Comment: is GetDatabase() returning a non const version?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI yes it does

Comment: @OmidCompSCI you can see in the question details.

Comment: You need to return `std::vector<GameObjectsDatabaseContainer*>` by reference.

Comment: @gudok like that `return &_container;` ?

Comment: @Venelin no, that is a pointer

Comment: @Venelin -- The client shouldn't even know how the database works internally when calling `GetDatabase()` and attempt to use it.  Your current code assumes that the client knows that a `std::vector` is used as a data store, and must call `push_back`.  Instead, the database class you have should just have an `Add()` or similar-named function, and it takes as a parameter the game object.  Then you don't need to get into the mess of where you are now.

Comment: Also, what happens if you find out that a `vector` isn't good enough, and instead you want to use another container that doesn't have `push_back`?  The client using `GetDatabase()` has to change their code, just because the database object is now using a different container.  With `Add()`, the client need not change a single line of code.

Answer (score 2):

`GetDatabase()` is returning `_container` *by value*, so it is returning a *copy* of `_container`.  Any changes the caller makes to that *copy* is not reflected in `_container`.

You need to return `_container` *by reference* instead:

```
std::vector<GameObjectsDatabaseContainer*>& GameObjectsDatabase::GetDatabase()  {
    return _container;
}
```

Comment: What about returning a const? How can I do that and is it going to help in that case as well ?

Comment: @Venelin You can return `const std::vector<GameObjectsDatabaseContainer*>&` instead. But you can't modify a `const vector` object, so `GetDatabase().push_back(...);` would not work in that case. But it might make sense for you to provide separate `GetDatabase()` overloads for read-only access (`const std::vector<GameObjectsDatabaseContainer*>& GetDatabase() const`) and writable access (`std::vector<GameObjectsDatabaseContainer*>& GetDatabase()`), depending on your actual needs.